# Unable to Call Function in Go debugger

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I am following the "Little Go Book" by Karl Seguin, in order to learn Go.

My working environment is Visual Studio Code.

Upon debugging, when I try to call a function from the debug console, i get the following error:
"function calls not allowed without using 'call'", if I try using "call fib(10)", i get "Unable to eval expression: "1:6: expected 'EOF', found fib". 
This is the function I am trying to evaluate:

```
//Fibonnaci
func fib(n int) int64 {
    if n == 0 {
        return 0
    } else if n == 1 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    }
}
```

If i try to call the function from the code itself ( from the main() for instance, it works perfectly).

However, if I set a breakpoint and try to call the same function from the debugger console, I get the below error:

```
Eval error: function calls not allowed without using 'call'
call fib(10)
Unable to eval expression: "1:6: expected 'EOF', found fib"
Failed to eval expression:  {
 "Expr": "call fib(10)",
 "Scope": {
  "goroutineID": 1,
  "frame": 0
 },
 "Cfg": {
  "followPointers": true,
  "maxVariableRecurse": 1,
  "maxStringLen": 64,
  "maxArrayValues": 64,
  "maxStructFields": -1
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like "Function calls via delve 'call' are not supported" yet github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2655) in microsoft/vscode-go repo :(

Comment: How is this answer helpful to anyone?  Are you even using the same environment as the asker?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier it doesn't matter, because all go UI debuggers are using delve under the hood. I demonstrated that it works well in console debugger mode.

Comment: Well, it does matter, because I have the same problem as the asker and your answer in no way helps me solve it.

Comment: try to run `dlv version`, i'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue [`vscode-go` issue 100](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/100) "debug: support function calls via delve 'call'" just got closed with [PR 101](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/pull/101) and [commit 5a7752c](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/commit/5a7752c81e0c667a7cd31baeed4dcae27308a3cc) / [CL 249377](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/vscode-go/+/249377)

> Delve supports function calls. Even though it is still experimental and can be applied only to a limited set of functions, this is a useful feature, many vscode-go users long for.
>
> Unlike other javascript/typescript debuggers, delve treats function calls specially and requires different call paths than usual expression evaluation.
> That is because Go is a compiled, runtime-managed GC language, calling a function safely from debugger is complex.
> DAP and VS Code UI does not distinguish function calls and other expression evaluation either, so we have to implement this in the same `evaluateRequest` context.
>
> We use a heuristic to guess which route (`call` or expression evaluation) we need to take based on evaluateRequest's request.

This is part of the [0.17.0 milestone](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/milestone/5), yet to be released, and available for now in the [nightly build](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/nightly.md).

Comment: I tried with https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/releases/tag/v0.17.0-rc.3 and still seeing the issue

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli I suppose that would be a good reason to update https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/100. Did you make an explicit call command to indicate the intention?

Comment: Fix is still not implemented in Jetbrains Goland as of 2022.2.5